# How to insert custom values with INSERT INTO + SELECT FROM?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

i would like to insert custom values along with table columns when i perform `INSERT INTO ...SELECT FROM ... WHERE` clause

```
INSERT INTO RoleMappingEmployee_Delete_History (
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey,
    SrKey,
    RoleKey,
    SubmittedDate,
    SubmittedBy,
    IsActive,
    DeletedBy,
    DeletedDateTime)
SELECT 
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey,
    SrKey,
    RoleKey,
    SubmittedDate,
    SubmittedBy,
    IsActive,
    DeletedBy,
    DeletedDateTime
FROM
    RoleMappingEmployee
WHERE
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey IN (25902,38188,25887)
```

i would like to insert values for `DeletedBy,DeletedDateTime` with custom values

Comment: Simply select literals instead of those two columns.

Comment: define custom values first

Comment: Why do you want to customize the log records (DeletedBy,...)?

Comment: `DeletedBy,DeletedDateTime`, have null values on insertion or better said on creation of roles but on removal of roles the `delete` log is recorded

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO RoleMappingEmployee_Delete_History (
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey,
    SrKey,
    RoleKey,
    SubmittedDate,
    SubmittedBy,
    IsActive,
    DeletedBy,
    DeletedDateTime)
SELECT 
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey,
    SrKey,
    RoleKey,
    SubmittedDate,
    SubmittedBy,
    IsActive,
    'peter',
    getdate()
FROM
    RoleMappingEmployee
WHERE
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey IN (25902,38188,25887)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set DeletedBy using ORIGINAL_LOGIN function, it will return the username who is performing the operation and help to avoid setting up value every time or parameter for this. Similarly you can use alternative in DeletedDateTime using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as below:

```
INSERT INTO RoleMappingEmployee_Delete_History (
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey,
    SrKey,
    RoleKey,
    SubmittedDate,
    SubmittedBy,
    IsActive,
    DeletedBy,
    DeletedDateTime)
SELECT 
    RoleMappingEmployeeKey,
    SrKey,
    RoleKey,
    SubmittedDate,
    SubmittedBy,
    IsActive,
    ORIGINAL_LOGIN(),
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM
    RoleMappingEmployee
WHERE RoleMappingEmployeeKey IN (25902,38188,25887)
```