# Copying columns from one table to another and add a new column from input form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I can copy columns from one table to another but my problem is to insert a data in the column of new table from an input form in a single query

Here I'd like to add this $tom in the column along with "name and price" and this $tom is from another input form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Enter the Product Code" />
<button name="add_to_cart">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mainstock');
if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart']))
{
$tom = $_SESSION['cust'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$query = "INSERT INTO sales (name,price,cust) SELECT name,price FROM tbl_product WHERE code = '$code' VALUES('{$tom}')";
$res = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling `session_start();` at the beginning of your file

Comment: This is a part of the code. My question is the $tom being added to a column named "cust"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the query for that one:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO sales (name,price,cust)
    SELECT name,price,'". $tom . "' FROM tbl_product;
";
```

Comment: Nope sir, that's why it is concatinated it is custom value. I think you should try this sir.

Comment: please refere to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767082/how-to-insert-custom-values-when-doing-insert-into-select-from

Comment: You are a life saver. I was stuck in that for few days now and my wife thinks I am going crazy..... wooh

Comment: No problem sir :)